# globalization in asp to change language french,urdu, english to dropdown list

Tags: asp.net

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="amenities.aspx.cs" Inherits="amenities"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server" >

    <div>

        Change Language
    
       <br />
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" >
       <asp:ListItem Value="en-US">English</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="ur">Urdu</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="fr">French</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
 
    <div>
        <img src="Images/2.jpg" style="position:relative;top:20px; height:300px;" />
        <p style="position:relative;left:454px; top: -300px; width: 619px;"><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" BackColor="<%$ Resources:Resource, BColor %>" ForeColor="<%$ Resources:Resource, FColor %>" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Text %>" ></asp:Label></p>


        <br /><img src="Images/3.jpg" style="position:relative; height:305px; top: -120px; left: 2px;" />
        <p style="position:relative;left:456px; top: -443px; width: 619px; bottom: 2332px;"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></p>


        <br/><img src="Images/4.jpg" style="position:relative;top:-180px; height:330px; left: 5px; width: 450px;" />
        <p style="position:relative; top: -530px; left: 460px; width: 617px;">The spectacular happens at all of our hotels and resorts in 80 countries across six continents. Let us find the one that’s right for you. The five-star international Islamabad Marriott Hotel is located at the foot steps of the famous Margalla Hills and is within close proximity to Rawal Lake, the town centre, President & Prime Minister Houses, Ministry of Foreign Affairs, Senate, Parliament House, Foreign Missions, World Bank, Government Offices, corporate sector, Print and Electronic media offices etc. The Hotel is a favourite rendezvous of politicians, diplomats, businessmen and movers and shakers of the country. Owing to the perfect location of the hotel, it hardly takes half an hour to commute between the Hotel, the Islamabad International Airport and the places of interests.</p>


        <br/><img src="Images/5.jpg" style="position:relative; top: -372px; left: 488px; width: 587px; height: 249px;" />
        <p style="position:relative; top: -638px; left: 1px; width: 481px;">The all-day dining restaurant offers an extensive selection of international & local flavors on a la carte menu but also buffet available for breakfast,lunch,hi-tea and dinner.The restaurant is popular for business lunches,casual dinners and Sunday Brunch</p>
         
        <br/><img src="Images/6.jpg" style="position:relative; top: -424px; left: 485px; height: 276px; width: 590px;" />
        <p style="position:relative; top: -718px; left: 2px; width: 478px;">A truly authentic Japenese Restaurant. As you dine with us you will not only savour the sumptous flavour but also the spectacular design that actually makes you feel that you are actually in Japan. Sakura is made to capture your heart and soul imagination. Jason's steakhouse concept is centered around exceptionally high quality food and warm elegent atmosphere. we serve best steak available and uncompromising quality.Two Private Rooms, both with the capacity of 04-persons.</p>
        
         </div>       
   </asp:Content>
```

I am trying to use globalization in asp.  I have created three resource files, `fr`,`ur` and `resource`. Languages are changing through selecting through drop down list, but I have to change other language too on the same page using drop down list.
`box1` language changed, but how to change `box2` language?
I have problems in `resource` file how to put 2 3 and 4 text in same resource `fr` resource file and how to link with it a label each resource file with a different label.

**http://prntscr.com/72uhug** please see the screenshot
**http://prntscr.com/72um08** resource file screenshot

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, make yourself well acquainted with the [**`concept of Globalization here`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and understand the use of Global and Local Resource files which exactly handle the kind of requirements you have. one simple definition is given [**`here too`**](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/localization/local-and-global-resources/).

So, In short, you should better generate Local resources for each language and override the `InitializeCulture()` method to set the Page's `UICulture` property to choose the appropriate language specific file as and when `dropdownlist` selection changes.

**STEP 1:** Generate Language specific resource files (`.resx` )

1. Select the option: Tools -> Generate Local Resource in your visual 
   studio. If suppose your aspx file is named: `default.aspx`, then 
   Visual Studio creates a new folder named `App_LocalResources`, and 
   within the `App_LocalResources` folder, a new file named 
   `default.aspx.resx`. In this `default.aspx.resx`, you should put the 
   Neutral Languge( English) text.
2. Next, create a resource file specific to French language

   In Solution Explorer, right-click the `default.aspx.resx` file, and
   click Copy.

   Right-click the `App_LocalResourcesfolder`, and then click Paste.

   Visual Studio creates a file named `Copy of default.aspx.resx`.

   Rename it to `default.aspx.fr.resx`. This resource file represents now 
   the Page content in French Language.

   Open `default.aspx.fr.resx` and add your French Text.
3. Same way create a language specific resource file for Urdu. [ File Name 
   thus will be: `default.aspx.ur.resx` ]

**STEP 2:** 
    Keep in mind that Asp.Net will pick up the appropriate Language specific 
    resource file based on the Pages' [**`UICulture`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) value. To set the 
    `UiCulture` property of Page, you Must override the `IntializeCulture()`
     method and set this property there:

// Use Request.Form["DropDownList1"] to access the DropDownlist value

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    if (Request.Form["DropDownList1"] != null)
    {
        String selectedLanguage = Request.Form["DropDownList1"];
        UICulture = selectedLanguage ;
        Culture = selectedLanguage ;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

[**`Read here`**](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/developing-multi-language-web-sites-with-asp-net) for a detailed tutorial on creating Multilanguage websites with Asp.net